# What permissions should /private/etc/hosts have on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, hosts, hosts-file

I had multiple terminal windows open using SSH to access a webserver behind reverse proxies and was making changes to my hosts file to alternate between the webserver and public ip. While not paying attention I accidently executed `sudo chmod 777 /private/etc/hosts` instead of just opening it with `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` now I'm not sure what permissions I should restore it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% ls -ld /private/etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  473 29 Jan 18:46 /private/etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks. Same as the majority of the other files in /private/etc* - just wanted to make sure.